# How to square a symmetric matrix using only upper or lower triangle?

Tags: r, matrix

I am attempting to calculate a topological overlap measure matrix without using `TOMsimilarity()` in the WGCNA package. In this calculation, I need to square a large (44000x44000) symmetric matrix.

Is it possible to do this by only using either the upper or lower triangle of the matrix?
I've seen it completed by creating a distance matrix of the symmetric matrix, but I was hoping someone could guide me in another direction.

The goal would be to complete the calculation as quick as possible.

Currently, the code is as so:

```
correlation<-cor(data)
adjacency<-(0.5*(1+correlation))^2

sum<-apply(adjacency,1, sum)
summatrix<-matrix(sum,ncol=length(sum),nrow=length(sum))
min.k<-pmin(summatrix, t(summatrix))
num<-adjacency%*%adjacency+adjacency
den<-min.k+1-adjacency
tom<-num/den
diag(tom)=1
disstom<-1-tom
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you done any searching of SO on this question? I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question.

Comment: I have searched, but maybe I'm not finding the duplicate question. I would appreciate if you/someone could link me to it.

Comment: I don't think I understood the question. I originally thought you had a distance "matrix" (which were the lower triangular values, and just wanted a square matrix. But reading it again it sounds like you don't really know how to get a proper "overlap measure" and are asking for statistical help.

Comment: Ah. nope. I can get the measure just fine. I'm just looking to see if anyone can help with squaring a symmetric matrix with either only the upper or lower triangle! :)

Comment: This is a great question. It's so much easier dealing w/ half of the huge datasets.